# outer function error using function including data-frame referencing

Tags: r

I've trying to get 3D surface using outer function. And a function that I defined refer column in data.frame. Below is brief code which reproducible.

test.txt is

```
   a    b   c
   1    0   0 
   2    0   0
   3    0   0
   6    0   0
   4    0   0
```

and code is

```
test<- read.table(file="test.txt",header=TRUE)

testf<-function(q,w){
test$b<-q
test$c<-w
sum(test$b)+sum(test$c)
}

x<-seq(1,10,by = 1)
y<-seq(0,30,by = 1)

z<-outer(x,y,testf)
```

result shown as error is

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "b", value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  : 
replacement has 310 rows, data has 5 

5.stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
"replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA) 

4.`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "b", value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,  ... 

3.`$<-`(`*tmp*`, "b", value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,  
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,  ... 

2. FUN(X, Y, ...) 

1. outer(x, y, testf)
```

function itself seems no problem since testf(1,1) works

```
> testf(1,1)
[1] 10
```

any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: the data.frame `test` you defined has `5` rows but you want replace it with `10` rows numeric vector. is this exactly what you want to do? because number of rows should be equal.

Comment: yes what I was going to do is to get each user defined function result which is calculated based on data frame by changing column data (In real code, I use MAPLLY to get input data from data frame column). is LOOP only way to get z axis result?

Comment: Or is there any other function that works as similar as  outer do?

Answer (score 0):

I think `for loop` is only way to generate z axis  value